# Why will sigchld_handler get a SIGTSTP too?

Tags: c, linux

I am making a small `shell` program.I want to suspend the foreground program in `sigtstp_handler`.And `sigchld_handler` to reap `zombie`.But when I type `ctrl z`,even if I do not have foreground program,the `sigchld_handler` still will get SIGTSTP.

```
    Signal(SIGINT,  sigint_handler);   /* ctrl-c */
    Signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstp_handler);  /* ctrl-z */
    Signal(SIGCHLD, sigchld_handler);  /* Terminated or stopped child */
```

handler

```
void sigchld_handler(int sig) 
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED)) > 0 ) {

        if (WIFEXITED(status)) {   /*checks if child terminated normally */
            deletejob(jobs, pid);
        }

        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {  /*checks if child was terminated by a signal that was not caught */
            printf("Job [%d] (%d) terminated by signal %d\n", pid2jid(pid), pid, WTERMSIG(status));
            deletejob(jobs,pid);
        }

        if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {     /*checks if child process that caused return is currently stopped */
            getjobpid(jobs, pid)->state = ST;
            printf("Job [%d] (%d) stopped by signal %d\n", pid2jid(pid), pid, WTERMSIG(status));
            //printf("[%d] Stopped %s\n", pid2jid(pid), jobs->cmdline);
        }

    }
    if (pid < 0 && errno != ECHILD) {
        printf("waitpid error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }

    return;
}


void sigtstp_handler(int sig) 
{   
    pid_t pid = fgpid(jobs);//Return PID of current foreground job, 0 if no such job 

    if (pid!=0){
        struct job_t *p = getjobpid(jobs, pid);
        printf("kill %d %s %d\n",p->pid,p->cmdline,p->state);

        kill(pid,SIGTSTP);
    }
    return;
}

void sigint_handler(int sig) 
{

    pid_t pid = fgpid(jobs);
    if (pid!=0){
        struct job_t *p = getjobpid(jobs, pid);
        printf("kill %d %s %d\n",p->pid,p->cmdline,p->state);
        kill(pid,SIGINT);
    }
    return;
}
```

I just `setpgid(0,0)`，after I `fork` a child process,then solved this problem.But I do not know what was really going on...

Comment: There is no `sigint_handler` in your code. Also show the code how you installed those handlers.

Comment: Did you mean `sigtstp_handler` will get the `SIGTSTP` signal?

Comment: of course，`sigtstp_handler` will get the `SIGTSTP`.My problem is `sigchld_handler` will get  `SIGTSTP`,even did not execute `kill`

Comment: How can you be sure the handler for a handler got called for another signal?

Comment: I add `printf` in handler

Comment: Note: you cannot use printf() inside a signal handler. It is not signal-safe. And I am afraid that your getjobpid() and deletejob() aren't signal safe, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You necessarily have a foreground process (if you use a terminal). If you didn't launched a subprocess then the shell is itself in the foreground state, so is the receiver of `TSTP`.
Foreground/background management needs more work than just signal handling. You need to set processes groups and declare which group is the foreground group.

The basic tasks are:

1. create a group when launching commands (`setpgid`)
2. declare the group as the foreground group if needed (`tcsetpgrp`)
3. make the shell aware of children state changes (handling of `SIGCHLD` and status `WIFSTOPPED`/`WSTOPPED` and manage your job list accordingly
4. make interactive shells insensible to `SIGTSTP` (ignore this signal in the shell)

Job controlling is a rough task to complete... Read documentation very carefully.

Comment: how to make interactive shells insensible ?In my handler,if pid==0,just means that it is a shell process.

Comment: I just `setpgid(0,0)`，after I fork a child process,then solved this problem.But I do not know what was really going on..

Answer (score 1):

You can search *when will SIGCHLD be sent*.

The definition is *when a child process stops or terminates*.

So if the parent process recieves a SIGTSTP, then it will send a SIGSTOP to child process.

In the end, the child will send a SIGCHLD to parent process.